# Optional in java 8 keep returning toString method from class

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have question about Java 8 from library `java.util.Optional.ofNullable;`
I have written following code but I hope that it will return value of field of class. But I keep getting toString method from class. What might be cause of behaving this code.

```
import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable;

public class Main12 {

    public static String getName(User user){
        return ofNullable(user).map(User::getName).orElse("noFound");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("ew");
        System.out.println(user);
    }

}
```

The result that I get from terminal is `User{id=null, name='ew', age=0, roles=[]}`.I hope that I will get value of name field from User class.

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public User(long id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public User(){

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", roles=" + roles +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User Class field and methods. When I send null parameter of into method getName from Main12 class. I will get null String but orElse from ofNullable not react what I have written there. Please if you have some idea how to fix it let me know.I never get noFound String or real name of field value of Class.

Comment: `public String getName() {return name == null ? "notFounf" : name; }`

Answer (score 3):

`public static string getName(User user)` has nothing to do with a method `getName` that you’ve define inside the `User` class.
In fact they’re completely different

So in the `main` method you don’t even call the static `getName` Method with Optionals inside - so it won’t even run.

Now, `toString` is called because you call `System.out.println(user)`. In this case Java automatically calls `toString`. That’s what happens.

`Optional.ofNullable` will “wrap” a reference to the object (even if its null) into the Optional wrapper.

I know, this could be a comment rather than the answer, but its kind of too long for comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking the static method you defined above your `main` anywhere. You could do the following in your User class:

```
public String getName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(name).orElse("noFound");
}
```

I have to state that this is not a good practice though. If `name` is really optional, it should **default** to something sensible, like your `Set` does.

Comment: Understand this is to show usage of Optional however note that 
    Optional.ofNullable(var).orElse(default)
 is, imho, is not ideal.   Usage of the trinary : 
    return (name == null) ?  "noFound" : name;   is clearer.